# Struts2 one class with 2 result bug?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2

i use struts 2 , definen 2 results for 1 class to output 2 pages code:

```
public String init() throws SystemException {
    return "index";
}



public String emailVerify() throws SystemException {
        return "emailVerify";
    }
```

and on struts xml

```
<action name="RegisterAction_*" class="com.app.action.RegisterAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="index">/WEB-INF/jsp/app/user_register.jsp</result>
        <result name="emailVerify">/WEB-INF/jsp/app/user_email_verify.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

init with result "success does work,but the emailVerify only work 1 time , if i reload the page it shows struts error, is this a bug?

Comment: There's not enough information (or it's poorly-worded) to help.

Answer (score 0):

fixed, this mvc has a Interceptor blocks non-init request